# How to clear form in AngularJS when there is no form name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope

I want to use the $setPristine() and $setUntouched() functions in Angular to clear form fields. However, they seem to only work with forms that have names. What if I have a form with no name and only a simple submit function?

I read the documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

This does not work:

```
    $scope.submit = function() {

        // blah blah

        // Resets the form fields to blank
        // I could simply do
        // $scope.field1 = '';
        // $scope.field2 = '';
        // But I want it to look cleaner

        This.$setPristine();
        This.$setUntouched();

    };
```

Comment: Do you see any issue in adding `name` to your form ? Angular will create instances of FormController only for named forms as the form name is used as a property representing the FormController instance for that particular form on your scope. Without any name, it won't be able to associate the FormController instance to any property name on the scope.

Comment: Ah thank you I see @Arkantos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular will create instances of `FormController` only for named forms as the form name is used as a property representing the FormController instance for that particular form on your scope. Without any name, it won't be able to associate the FormController instance to any property name on the scope.

For example, given the following markup

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">

    <form name="myForm" id="myForm" ng-submit="handleSubmit()">
      /* Some Markup */
    </form>

</div>
```

In your MyController, `$scope` has a property called `myForm` representing the `FormController` instance and you can call methods or access properties like below.

```
$scope.myForm.$valid
$scope.myForm.$setPristine();
$scope.myForm.$setUntouched();
```

Calling `setPristine()` and `setUntouched()` will only change the form state from `dirty` to `pristine` and `untouched` as evident from the classes added to your form but do not reset the form fields. There's no public method exposed on `FormController` to reset the form fields and the corresponding model values but you can achieve that simply with a small change in the way you're binding values using `ng-model`. Using a dot(.) in your models is a good practice as it will allow to capture  all the form state in a single object and also prevents you from creating shadow properties.

In your HTML,

```
<input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullname" ng-model="data.fullName"/>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="data.email" />
```

In your controller,

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
      .controller('MyController', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
    fullName : '',
    email : ''
  };


  $scope.resetForm = function(){
   /* reset the data to a new object so that all the properties
    * of form are reset
    */
    $scope.data = {};
  };

});
```

Here's a sample [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rewBrV) in action. Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks this is what I suspected. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

use "this" instead of "This"

try:

```
$scope.currentRecord={};
```

Comment: I read the post where you got that from, I already included that in the question. I am looking for a cleaner solution

Comment: This is not a bad solution at all. Perhaps it's the only solution for you

Comment: if you don't want to use names, i don't know any other solution.

Comment: @OneMoreQuestion.. you can refer to my answer for a simple solution.

Comment: @LukasLiesis Thank you, this is probably the only solution with no form names